# Use of boolean queries in lucene

Tags: lucene

I have a general doubt regarding Lucene query.

I have two fields country and city.

The query can be constructed in two ways.

Either construct query like country:(Sri Lanka) AND city :(Colombo)

or the same query can be constructed with boolean query and can be combined together.

What is the difference with these two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first option is to make a query string and pass it to `QueryParser` (correct me if not), there is no difference at all. Query parser will make the same `BooleanQuery`, you can double check this by printing its class name.

Yet, if you're using Lucene it's best to move away from thinking in boolean logic. [Boolean logic makes terrible scores](https://lucidworks.com/blog/why-not-and-or-and-not/).